# Filter in Laravel with checkbox

Tags: php, html, laravel, backend, laravel-9

I need the controller to send only the information corresponding to the name sent by the checkbox filter, but it sends all queries to all variables, making the forelse loop of the view generate unnecessary cards with incorrect formatting.

I never had done something like this, so please help.

Controller:

```
public function index(Request $request){

$vests = $request->input('vest');
$query = Vests::query();
    $enems= $query->when($vests == 'enem', function ($enems) {
        return $enems->where('facu_vest', 'enem');
    })->get();

    $fuvests= $query->when($vests == 'fuvest', function ($fuvests) {
        return $fuvests->where('facu_vest', 'fuvest');
    })->get();

    $unesps= $query->when($vests == 'unesp', function ($unesps) {
        return $unesps->where('facu_vest', 'unesp');
    })->get();

    $unicamps= $query->when($vests == 'unicamp', function ($unicamps) {
        return $unicamps->where('facu_vest', 'unicamp');
    })->get();
        return view("vestibulares/vest", ['enems' => $enems, 'unesps' => $unesps, 'fuvests' => $fuvests, 'unicamps' => $unicamps]);

    }
```

Filter:

```
              <div class="item">
                  <form action="/vest" method="POST">
                      @csrf
                  <a class="sub-btn"><i class="bi bi-card-checklist" ></i>Vestibulares<i style="font-size: 18px;" class="bi bi-chevron-right dropdown cor"></i></a>
                  <div class="sub-menu">
                  <a style="margin-bottom: 1px; color: #158291; font-weight: bold;" href="{{asset('vest')}}" class="sub-item">FILTROS</a>
                  <hr style="color: #727272; margin: auto; width: 85%; height: 2px;">
                  <a style="margin-top: 1px; color: #158291; text-align: left;" href="" class="sub-item">Vestibular</a>
                  <!----------------------------> 
                  <div style="margin-left: 29px;" class="form-check">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="vesta" value="todos" id="flexCheckDefault">
                    <label style="margin-left: 5px;" class="form-check-label sub-item" for="flexCheckDefault">Todos</label> 
                  </div>

                  <div style="margin-left: 29px;" class="form-check">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="vest[]" value="enem" id="flexCheckDefault">
                    <label style="margin-left: 5px;" class="form-check-label sub-item" for="flexCheckDefault">ENEM</label> 
                  </div>

                  <div style="margin-left: 29px;" class="form-check">
                    <input  class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="vest[]" value="unicamp" id="flexCheckDefault" name="facu[]">
                    <label style="margin-left: 5px;" class="form-check-label sub-item" for="flexCheckDefault">UNICAMP</label> 
                  </div>

                  <div style="margin-left: 29px;" class="form-check"> 
                    <input  class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="vest[]" value="fuvest" id="flexCheckDefault" name="facu[]">
                    <label style="margin-left: 5px;" class="form-check-label sub-item" for="flexCheckDefault">FUVEST</label> 
                  </div>

                  <div style="margin-left: 29px;" class="form-check">
                    <input  class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="vest[]" value="unesp" id="flexCheckDefault" name="facu[]">
                    <label style="margin-left: 5px;" class="form-check-label sub-item" for="flexCheckDefault">UNESP</label> 
                  </div>
                  
                  <!----------------------------> 
                  <a style="margin-top: 1px; color: #158291; text-align: left;" href="#" class="sub-item">Ano</a>
                  <!----------------------------> 
                  <div style="margin-left: 29px;" class="form-check">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="todosa" id="flexCheckDefault">
                    <label style="margin-left: 5px;" class="form-check-label sub-item" for="flexCheckDefault">Todos</label> 
                  </div>
                  
                  <div style="margin-left: 29px;" class="form-check">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="ano[]" value="2017" id="flexCheckDefault">
                    <label style="margin-left: 5px;" class="form-check-label sub-item" for="flexCheckDefault">2017</label> 
                  </div>

                  <div style="margin-left: 29px;" class="form-check">
                    <input  class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="ano[]" value="2018" id="flexCheckDefault">
                    <label style="margin-left: 5px;" class="form-check-label sub-item" for="flexCheckDefault">2018</label> 
                  </div>

                  <div style="margin-left: 29px;" class="form-check"> 
                    <input  class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="ano[]" value="2019" id="flexCheckDefault">
                    <label style="margin-left: 5px;" class="form-check-label sub-item" for="flexCheckDefault">2019</label> 
                  </div>

                  <div style="margin-left: 29px;" class="form-check"> 
                    <input  class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="ano[]" value="2020" id="flexCheckDefault">
                    <label style="margin-left: 5px;" class="form-check-label sub-item" for="flexCheckDefault">2020</label> 
                  </div>

                  <div style="margin-left: 29px;" class="form-check"> 
                    <input  class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="ano[]" value="2021" id="flexCheckDefault">
                    <label style="margin-left: 5px;" class="form-check-label sub-item" for="flexCheckDefault">2021</label> 
                  </div>

                  <div style="margin-left: 29px; padding-bottom: 30px;" class="form-check">
                    <input  class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="ano[]" value="2022" id="flexCheckDefault">
                    <label style="margin-left: 5px;" class="form-check-label sub-item" for="flexCheckDefault">2022</label> 
                  </div>
                  <!----------------------------> 
                  </div>

                  <button class="entrar-button" type="submit"><i class="bi bi-box-arrow-in-right"></i>    Filtrar</button>
                </form>
                </div>
```

View:

```
@extends('layout')
@section('container')

    <!--link meu css-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/stylev.css">



<div class="container geral">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
@forelse($enems as $enems)
    <form action="/vest/baixar/{{$enems['ano_vest']}}" method="get">
        @csrf
      <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-xs-12 my-3 ">
        <div style="border: none; position: relative; border-radius: 0; align-items: center; display: flex; flex-direction: row; flex-wrap: wrap; justify-content: center;" class="card h-100">
            <div style="position: absolute; top: 0; text-align: center;">
                <h1 class="enem">ENEM</h1>
                <p class="ano">{{$enems['ano_vest']}}</p>
            </div>
            <div style="display: flex; justify-content: space-between;">

        <!--card 1-->
      <div style="height: 330px;  max-width: 250px;  margin: 80px 15px 10px 15px;"><!--rr-->
        <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; align-items: center;" class="card  h-100">
            <img src="{{asset($enems['img_vest'])}}" class="img card-img-top p-2" alt="">
            <h1 style="color: #158291; padding-top: 10px;" class="card-title textdisc">Primeiro dia</h1>
            <h1 style="color: #158291;  padding: 0 27px;" class="card-title textdisc">Linguagens e Ciências Humanas</h1>

            <div style="display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center; padding-top: 25px; padding-bottom: 5px;">
                <ul style="list-style: none; margin: 0; padding: 0;">
                    <li><a href="/vest/baixar/{{$enems['faseum_vest']}}"><button type="submit"><h1 class="card-title textenem"><i style="margin-right: 7px; color: #727272;" class="bi bi-download"></i>Azul</h1></button></a></li>
                    <li><a href="/vest/baixar/{{$enems['fasedois_vest']}}"><button type="submit"><h1 class="card-title textenem"><i style="margin-right: 7px; color: #727272;" class="bi bi-download"></i>Amarelo</h1></button></a></li>
                    <li><a href="/vest/baixar/{{$enems['fase3_vest']}}"><button type="submit"><h1 class="card-title textenem"><i style="margin-right: 7px; color: #727272;" class="bi bi-download"></i>Cinza</h1></button></a></li>
                    <li><a href="/vest/baixar/{{$enems['fase4_vest']}}"><button type="submit"><h1 class="card-title textenem"><i style="margin-right: 7px; color: #727272;" class="bi bi-download"></i>Rosa</h1></button></a></li>
                </ul>

                <ul style="list-style: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; margin-left: 10px;">
                    <li><h1  class="card-title textenem"><a href=""><i style="margin-right: 7px; color: #727272;" class="bi bi-download"></i></a>Gabarito</h1></li>
                    <li><h1  class="card-title textenem"><a href=""><i style="margin-right: 7px; color: #727272;" class="bi bi-download"></i></a>Gabarito</h1></li>
                    <li><h1  class="card-title textenem"><a href=""><i style="margin-right: 7px; color: #727272;" class="bi bi-download"></i></a>Gabarito</h1></li>
                    <li><h1  class="card-title textenem"><a href=""><i style="margin-right: 7px; color: #727272;" class="bi bi-download"></i></a>Gabarito</h1></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div><!--fim do card-->
    </div><!--fim da coluna-->

    <!--card 2-->
    <div style="height: 330px;  max-width: 250px;  margin: 80px 15px 10px 15px; ">
      <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; align-items: center;" class="card  h-100">
          <img src="{{asset($enems['img_vest'])}}" class="img card-img-top p-2" alt="">
          <h1 style="color: #158291; padding-top: 10px;" class="card-title textdisc">Segundo dia</h1>
          <h1 style="color: #158291; padding: 0 15px;" class="card-title textdisc">Ciências da Natureza e Matemática</h1>

          <div style="display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center; padding-top: 25px; padding-bottom: 5px;">
              <ul style="list-style: none; margin: 0; padding: 0;">
                <li><a href="/vest/baixar/{{$enems['faseum_vest']}}"><button type="submit"><h1 class="card-title textenem"><i style="margin-right: 7px; color: #727272;" class="bi bi-download"></i>Azul</h1></button></a></li>
                <li><a href="/vest/baixar/{{$enems['fasedois_vest']}}"><button type="submit"><h1 class="card-title textenem"><i style="margin-right: 7px; color: #727272;" class="bi bi-download"></i>Amarelo</h1></button></a></li>
                <li><a href="/vest/baixar/{{$enems['fase3_vest']}}"><button type="submit"><h1 class="card-title textenem"><i style="margin-right: 7px; color: #727272;" class="bi bi-download"></i>Cinza</h1></button></a></li>
                <li><a href="/vest/baixar/{{$enems['fase4_vest']}}"><button type="submit"><h1 class="card-title textenem"><i style="margin-right: 7px; color: #727272;" class="bi bi-download"></i>Rosa</h1></button></a></li>
              </ul>

              <ul style="list-style: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; margin-left: 10px;">
                  <li><h1  class="card-title textenem"><a href=""><i style="margin-right: 7px; color: #727272;" class="bi bi-download"></i></a>Gabarito</h1></li>
                  <li><h1  class="card-title textenem"><a href=""><i style="margin-right: 7px; color: #727272;" class="bi bi-download"></i></a>Gabarito</h1></li>
                  <li><h1  class="card-title textenem"><a href=""><i style="margin-right: 7px; color: #727272;" class="bi bi-download"></i></a>Gabarito</h1></li>
                  <li><h1  class="card-title textenem"><a href=""><i style="margin-right: 7px; color: #727272;" class="bi bi-download"></i></a>Gabarito</h1></li>
              </ul>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</form>
@empty
    <h1>sem valor</h1>
@endforelse


    <!-- FUVEST -->

@forelse($fuvests as $fuvests)
    @csrf
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-xs-12 my-3 ">
    <div style="border: none; position: relative; border-radius: 0; align-items: center; display: flex; flex-direction: row; flex-wrap: wrap; justify-content: center;" class="card h-100">
        <div style="position: absolute; top: 0; text-align: center;">
            <h1 class="enem">FUVEST</h1>
            <p class="ano">{{$fuvests['ano_vest']}}</p>
        </div>
        <div style="display: flex; justify-content: space-between;">

  <!--card 1-->
  <div style="height: 310px;  max-width: 250px;  margin: 80px 15px 10px 15px;">
    <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; align-items: center;" class="card  h-100">
        <img style="margin-left: 80px; margin-right: 80px;" src="{{asset($fuvests['img_vest'])}}" class="img card-img-top p-2" alt="">
        <h1 style="color: #158291; padding-top: 10px; " class="card-title textdisc">Primeira fase</h1>
            <ul style="list-style: none; margin: 0; padding: 0;">
                <li><a href="/vest/baixar1/{{$fuvests['facu_vest']}}/{{$fuvests['ano_vest']}}"><button style="border:none; background-color: white;" type="submit"><h1 class="card-title textenem"><i style="margin-right: 7px; color: #727272;" class="bi bi-download"></i>Primeira Fase</h1></button></a></li>
            </ul>

            <h1 style="color: #158291; text-align: center; padding-top: 5px;" class="card-title textdisc">Segunda fase</h1>
                        <ul style="list-style: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; padding-bottom: 15px;">
                            <li><a href="/vest/baixar2/{{$fuvests['facu_vest']}}/{{$fuvests['ano_vest']}}"><button style="border:none; background-color: white;" type="submit"><h1 class="card-title textenem"><i style="margin-right: 7px; color: #727272;" class="bi bi-download"></i>Primeiro Dia</h1></button></a></li>
                            <li><a href="/vest/baixar3/{{$fuvests['facu_vest']}}/{{$fuvests['ano_vest']}}"><button type="submit" style="border:none; background-color: white;"><h1 class="card-title textenem"><i style="margin-right: 7px; color: #727272;" class="bi bi-download"></i>Segundo Dia</h1></button></a></li>
                            <li>
                                @if($fuvests['ano_vest'] == '2017')
                                    <!--Display the image for the first two items-->
                                    <li><a href="/vest/baixar4/{{$fuvests['facu_vest']}}/{{$fuvests['ano_vest']}}"><button type="submit" style="border:none; background-color: white;"><h1 class="card-title textenem"><i style="margin-right: 7px; color: #727272;" class="bi bi-download"></i>Terceiro Dia</h1></button></a></li>                                   

                                @endif
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                @if($fuvests['ano_vest'] == '2018')
                                    <!--Display the image for the first two items-->
                                    <li><a href="/vest/baixar4/{{$fuvests['facu_vest']}}/{{$fuvests['ano_vest']}}"><button type="submit" style="border:none; background-color: white;"><h1 class="card-title textenem"><i style="margin-right: 7px; color: #727272;" class="bi bi-download"></i>Terceiro Dia</h1></button></a></li>                                   

                                @endif
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

</div>
</div>
</div>
@empty
    <h1>sem valor</h1>
@endforelse


<!-- UNESP -->


@forelse ($unesps as $unesp)

    @csrf
    @if($unesp["ano_vest"] === "2020")
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-xs-12 my-3 ">
  <div style="border: none; position: relative; border-radius: 0; align-items: center; display: flex; flex-direction: row; flex-wrap: wrap; justify-content: center;" class="card h-100">
      <div style="position: absolute; top: 0; text-align: center;">
          <h1 class="enem">UNESP</h1>
          <p class="ano">{{$unesp['ano_vest']}}</p>
      </div>
      <div style="display: flex; justify-content: space-between;">

<!--card 1-->
<div style="height: 310px;  max-width: 250px;  margin: 80px 15px 10px 15px;">
  <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; align-items: center;" class="card  h-100">
      <img style="margin-left: 80px; margin-right: 80px;" src="{{asset($unesp['img_vest'])}}" class="img card-img-top p-2" alt="">
      <h1 style="color: #158291; padding-top: 10px; " class="card-title textdisc">Unesp-2020</h1>

          <ul style="list-style: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; padding-bottom: 116px;">
            <li><a href="/vest/baixar1/{{$unesp['facu_vest']}}/{{$unesp['ano_vest']}}"><button type="submit" style="border:none; background-color: white;"><h1 class="card-title textenem"><i style="margin-right: 7px; color: #727272;" class="bi bi-download"></i>Unesp-2020</h1></button></a></li>
          </ul>
  </div>
</div>

</div>
</div>
</div>

    @else

<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-xs-12 my-3 ">
  <div style="border: none; position: relative; border-radius: 0; align-items: center; display: flex; flex-direction: row; flex-wrap: wrap; justify-content: center;" class="card h-100">
      <div style="position: absolute; top: 0; text-align: center;">
          <h1 class="enem">UNESP</h1>
          <p class="ano">{{$unesp['ano_vest']}}</p>
      </div>
      <div style="display: flex; justify-content: space-between;">

<!--card 1-->
<div style="height: 310px;  max-width: 250px;  margin: 80px 15px 10px 15px;">
  <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; align-items: center;" class="card  h-100">
      <img style="margin-left: 80px; margin-right: 80px;" src="{{asset($unesp['img_vest'])}}" class="img card-img-top p-2" alt="">
      <h1 style="color: #158291; padding-top: 10px; " class="card-title textdisc">Primeira fase</h1>

          <ul style="list-style: none; margin: 0; padding: 0;">
            <li><a href="/vest/baixar1/{{$unesp['facu_vest']}}/{{$unesp['ano_vest']}}"><button type="submit" style="border:none; background-color: white;"><h1 class="card-title textenem"><i style="margin-right: 7px; color: #727272;" class="bi bi-download"></i>Primeira fase</h1></button></a></li>
          </ul>

          <h1 style="color: #158291; text-align: center; padding-top: 5px;" class="card-title textdisc">Segunda fase</h1>
            <ul style="list-style: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; padding-bottom: 60px;">
                <li><a href="/vest/baixar2/{{$unesp['facu_vest']}}/{{$unesp['ano_vest']}}"><button type="submit"style="border:none; background-color: white;"><h1 class="card-title textenem"><i style="margin-right: 7px; color: #727272;" class="bi bi-download"></i>Segunda fase</h1></button></a></li>            </ul>
  </div>
</div>

</div>
</div>
</div>

@endif
@empty
    <h1>sem valor</h1>
@endforelse


<!-- UNICAMPS -->
@forelse ($unicamps as $unicamp)

    @csrf
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-xs-12 my-3 ">
  <div style="border: none; position: relative; border-radius: 0; align-items: center; display: flex; flex-direction: row; flex-wrap: wrap; justify-content: center;" class="card h-100">
      <div style="position: absolute; top: 0; text-align: center;">
          <h1 class="enem">UNICAMP</h1>
          <p class="ano">{{$unicamp['ano_vest']}}</p>
      </div>
      <div style="display: flex; justify-content: space-between;">

<!--card 1-->
<div style="height: 310px;  max-width: 250px;  margin: 80px 15px 10px 15px;">
  <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; align-items: center;" class="card  h-100">
      <img style="margin-left: 80px; margin-right: 80px;" src="{{asset($unicamp['img_vest'])}}" class="img card-img-top p-2" alt="">
      <h1 style="color: #158291; padding-top: 10px; " class="card-title textdisc">Primeira fase</h1>
      <ul style="list-style: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; padding-bottom: 20px;">
        <li><a href="/vest/baixar1/{{$unicamp['facu_vest']}}/{{$unicamp['ano_vest']}}"><button type="submit" style="border:none; background-color: white;"><h1 class="card-title textenem"><i style="margin-right: 7px; color: #727272;" class="bi bi-download"></i>Primeira fase</h1></button></a></li>

        </ul>


        <h1 style="color: #158291; text-align: center; padding-top: 5px;" class="card-title textdisc">Segunda fase</h1>
                <ul style="list-style: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; padding-bottom: 60px;">
                <li><a href="/vest/baixar2/{{$unicamp['facu_vest']}}/{{$unicamp['ano_vest']}}"><button type="submit" style="border:none; background-color: white;"><h1 class="card-title textenem"><i style="margin-right: 7px; color: #727272;" class="bi bi-download"></i>Segunda fase</h1></button></a></li>
                </ul>
  </div>
</div>

</div>
</div>
</div>
@empty
    <h1>sem valor</h1>
@endforelse
</div>
</div>

@endsection
```

Rote:

`Route::post('vest', [VestsController::class, 'index']);`

Comment: You should use ajax to fetch related data from controller and append it to your view using JS.